# A clean way of closing a reading window capable of analysing strings of variable length in Python?

Tags: python, frame, sequence

I'm trying to create a program that can analyze a string sequence. Currently, my program is capable of examining the sequence character by character, but I don't know how to cleanly get it to recognize the end of the string, which will be variable.

```
str_exp="ABCDAABKLYWAKAT"

n=0
x=5

while n<=10:

  window=str_exp[n:x]
  print window,
  n+=1
  x+=1

  countA=window.count('A') 
  print countA
```

This should output:

```
ABCDA 2
BCDAA 2
CDAAB 2
DAABK 2
AABKL 2
ABKLY 1
BKLYW 0
KLYWA 1
LYWAK 1
YWAKA 2
WAKAT 2
```

Comment: You just want to know how long the string is? That's `len(str_exp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the condition on your `while` loop to be based on `len(str_exp)`, which will detect the length of the string.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out the arithmetic, because you've got all the basic pieces

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of a string (or many other Python types) with `len(s)`. So, one way to do this is to replace this line:

```
while n<=10:
```

with this:

```
while n<=len(str_exp) - 5:
```

However, you usually don't want a loop like `n = 0 … while n<=bound: … n+=1` in Python; it's better to replace all three lines with just `for n in range(bound):`. `range(5)` just means `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, and `for n in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:` means "run this loop with `n=0`, then with `n=1`, …, then with `n=4`", which is exactly what `n = 0 … while n<=4: … n+=1` means. So:

```
for n in range(len(str_exp)-5):
```

However, either way, it's pretty easy to screw that up and get an off-by-one error, where you either miss the last window, or go too far and pass it. (Fortunately, in Python, that means you'll just print a window with only 4 characters instead of 5, rather than, say, crashing with a segfault.) So, it's often better to think of a way to rewrite your code so you don't need that.

Sometimes, it's easier to think backward than forward. It takes a moment of reflection to make sure that I want to go from `0` to `len(str_exp) - 5`… but if I define the slices backward, it's obvious to me that I can just go from `5` to `len(str_exp)`. If the same is true for you, you can rewrite it like this:

```
for n in range(5, len(str_exp)):
    window=str_exp[n-5:n]
    …
```

Or, if neither one is obvious, you can define things a different way. For example, if you want to go until the window is not 5 characters long anymore:

```
for n in range(len(str_exp)):
    window=str_exp[n:x]
    if len(window) < 5:
        break
    …
```

There are even more radical ways to rethink this. To give you an example, you can write a general-purpose `window` function, and then your loop just looks like this:

```
for window in iterwindow(str_exp, 5):
    …
```

You probably wouldn't be able to write, or even read, this `iterwindow` function yet. It looks something like this:

```
def window(iterable, windowlength):
  window = ''
  for i in iter(iterable):
    if len(window) == windowlength:
      window = window[1:]
    window = window + i
    if len(window) == windowlength:
      yield window
```

But if someone else had written it (in the standard library, or a module you can find on PyPI), you could use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
windowlen = 5
for end in range(windowlen,len(str_exp)):
    print str_exp[end-windowlen:end]
```

Range just creates a list of numbers. By having the last number be the last index in `str_exp`, and by creating the start of the window with reference to the end, you ensure you never run off the end.

The the `range` expression into your python shell to see what it does.